# How to fix JavaScript with Brackets

Tags: text-editor

[image: the JavaScript is not working right]

I'm new to Ubuntu and I have this problem when I start an HTML file and then want to add a JavaScript script to it, Brackets shows errors even when everything is correct.

If I get the code and just insert it in the browser console it works but Brackets still shows its wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: Those just look like "you're not respecting the standards" complaints, they are not really errors.

Answer (score 4):

I have never used brackets, but what you are seeing is JSLint warnings - they are telling you is your coding style is not in agreement with JSLint. There must be preferences, or configuration somewhere that enables you to turn JSLint off.

Alternatively, you can engage in the exercise of following the warnings and cleaning up the code. You will learn to build your Javascript in a way that is more likely to make your teammates happy.

Answer (score 1):

Change the preferred linters in the preferences file of Brackets:

```
"language": {
    "javascript": {
        "linting.prefer": ["JSHint"],
        "linting.usePreferredOnly": true
    }
},
```

Preferences can be found here: Debug > Open Preferences File

More info:

https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences

http://the-sourceterous.ghost.io/brackets-editor-disable-jslint-and-use-jshint-instead-2/

Good luck!